# ZXing Library not providing Intent result

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using ZXing Library as a library to my Android project. However whenever a barcode is scanned the ZXing Capture activity doesn't provide the result to my activity, it just stands there as if the code had been scanned normally via the application.

My current code is:

```
discount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(DiscountActivity.this, CaptureActivity.class);
            intent.setAction("com.google.xzing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }

    });

}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.discount_dialog);

            dialog.show();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Yes I've tried it simply doesn't come back to onActivityResult, only if I press the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong, and more complex than it needs to be. This is all you should be doing: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I have core.jar in my lib/ folder how can I use IntentIntegrator?

Comment: "com.google.xzing" is misspelled, and I am not sure that you are actually invoking the app's `CaptureActivity` vs yours. It also does not look like you're declaring the result handler in the right class.